# UIBGTaskScheduler will work if app is killed?

Tags: xamarin, background-process, ios13, ios-background-mode, uibackgroundtask

I am working on app in which I want to schedule an alarm like in Android Alarm service.

I know there is UIBGTaskScheduler in iOS 13 but I am unable to identify if this can work when app is killed?

I have searched a lot but couldn’t find about the process when app is killed.

I have seen lots of examples are there as well but couldn’t find the answer I was looking for.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `BGAppRefreshTask ` .,which is a special type of Background Task which we can use for app data update. One thing that makes this task type very special is the user behavior. iOS learns how often and at what time the user is running your app and tries to run BGAppRefreshTask at a time when the user is not likely to be using the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but will that work even when the app is killed?

Comment: Background Task only support like media player . In your case , it will be better to use local notification .